# View homepage in a preview mode

Tags: homepage, previews

Is there any way to view your homepage in a preview mode, so that I can check how my posts will look on the homepage before publishing them (i.e. to make sure the featured image looks right etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can set your post to `private` to view it privately on the homepage.

> Once you change the visibility to private, the post or page status
>   changes to "Privately Published" as shown. Private posts are
>   automatically published but not visible to anyone but those with the
>   appropriate permission levels (Editor or Administrator).

See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Private_Content).

---

Here is one idea to view `draft` posts on the site:

Let's reuse the `preview` parameter to add the `draft` posts to the current page view, for example:

```
- example.com/?preview=true
- example.com/2014/01/?preview=true
```

We then modify all frontend queries, for logged in users, with:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', function( $where ){
   if( ! is_admin() 
       && is_user_logged_in() 
       && 'true' === get_query_var( 'preview' ) 
       && ! is_singular() )
   {
        global $wpdb;
        $from = sprintf( "%s.post_status = 'publish'", $wpdb->posts ) ;
        if( current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) )
        {
            // add drafts from all users:
            $to = sprintf( "%s.post_status IN ( 'publish', 'draft' ) ", $wpdb->posts ) ;
        }
        else
        {
            // add drafts from current user:
            $sql = " ( %s.post_status = 'publish' 
                       OR ( %s.post_status = 'draft'  AND %s.post_author = %d ) ) ";
            $to = sprintf( $sql, 
                           $wpdb->posts, 
                           $wpdb->posts, 
                           $wpdb->posts, 
                           get_current_user_id() 
                  );
        }
        $where  = str_ireplace( $from, $to, $where );       
   }
   return $where;
});
```

but we could use `is_main_query()` to restrict the modifications to the main query.

ps: this might need some testing or adjustments  ... but you get the idea ;-)

Comment: Private! I like your idea. I was thinking about the code, and you trough a simple idea.

Comment: That's a smart and _very_ nifty way to do it. +1